# Assign a customer cart to another customer programmatically Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want to assign a customer product on the cart to another customer cart in Magento 2.

Somewhere is saw that we can achieve the same on Magento 1.x from

```
Mage::getModel('checkout/quote')->load($quoteId)->setCustomerId($customerId)->save();
```

I first tried the same on Magento 1.x it assigned the cart to another customer but the problem was, after assigning when the customer removed the product from the cart the product will be removed from other customer cart too.

Can anyone help me out here? How can I achieve this on Magento 2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a customer cart to another customer by **below code :**

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$collection = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session')->getQuote()->load($quoteId)->setCustomerId($customerId)->save();
```

Comment: OK i will try this

Comment: Is this helpful for you?

Comment: Hi Akshay , I don't think it is working. Have you tried it.

Comment: As per magento 1.x

Comment: As per Magento 1.x:Mage::getModel('checkout/quote')->load($quoteId)->setCustomerId($customerId)->save();

Comment: Actually I just don't want to convert the code of Magento 1.x to 2 but my intention is to achieve what i have mentioned above, the methods could be any, the above code snippet was just reference. But it is not working.Can you suggest any other solution.